# How do you make such a shape in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have been trying to make stuff I see all over the internet in order to train my Photoshop skills, but couldn't seem to figure out how to make such a shape?

[image]

Comment: Hi user3029101, what have you tried? This is a basic shape in photoshop using the polygon tool.

Comment: Please make an [edit] to your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Hexagon, another smaller hexagon, delete.. trace what's left with pen tool for a proper shape.

Comment: @Darth_Vader Im sorry but I have not tried anything yet....i know its 2 hexagons but how do you achieve so much perfection and symmetry?

Comment: default hexagons are symmetrical, you'd have to deliberately make it asymmetrical for it to not be.

Comment: Its going to be hard to expect someone to help you when you have indicated you havent given much effort.  If you can show effort i am sure the community would help provide you with some advise.  I can even recall some similar questions that could be of assistance if you were to search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in custom shape tool>select hexagon frame 
it will give you heaxagon frame similar like this image just cut the edge through pen tool and you will get the similar output

Comment: Hello Anubhav Pun, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. Could you please explain bit more? You give a few steps but they can be hard to follow. We love answers that are thorough and complete here! If you want to know more about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!